# how to pass ajax return value php variable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i know this question is asked many times, but non of them having right solution. i am using ajax to get the response from PHP Page. After getting the response i want to use the value in PHP variable. Below code is getting result but i am confused with the usage of it.

below is my index.php

```
function getLocation() {
     if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError);
        } else {
            alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
    }

    function geoSuccess(position) {
        var glat = position.coords.latitude;
        var glng = position.coords.longitude;
        //alert("lat:" + glat + " lng:" + glng);
        geocoding(glat,glng);
      }

    function geoError() {
        alert("Geocoder failed.");
    }
    function geocoding(glat,glng){
        $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'geolocation.php',
        data:'latitude='+glat+'&longitude='+glng,
        success:function(result){
            if(result){
               $("#locationg").val(result);
               $("#htmllocation").html(result);
           }
        }
    });
   }
```

geolocation.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST['latitude']) && !empty($_POST['longitude'])){
    //Send request and receive json data by latitude and longitude
    $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.trim($_POST['latitude']).','.trim($_POST['longitude']).'&sensor=false';
    $json = @file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($json);
    $status = $data->status;
    if($status=="OK"){
        //Get address from json data
        $location = $data->results[0]->formatted_address;
        //$location = $data->results[0]->address_components;

        for($j=0;$j<count($data->results[0]->address_components);$j++){
               $cn=array($data->results[0]->address_components[$j]->types[0]);
           if(in_array("locality", $cn))
           {
            $city= $data->results[0]->address_components[$j]->long_name;
           }
            }

     }else{
        echo 'No Location';
    }

    echo $city;
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
    $city='<span id="htmllocation"></span>';
?>
```

when i `echo $city` i am getting city name but in inspect elements its showing like

```
<span id="htmllocation">Visakhapatnam</span>
```

issue is that i can not use this in MYSQL because it in html format, and i just want to get only the city name nothing else.

i hope my issue is clear, please leave a comment if not clear.

Comment: You can use strip_tags function to remove HTML tags and can get city only.

Comment: Where do you want to use the city's name?

Comment: in index.php page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The user locates `example.com/index.php`, it displays a webpage.
- You get the user's location from JS.
- You send it back to the server, and get the addresses of that location.
- Then you want to access the addresses from `index.php`

Is that correct? If so, you can't do it. Things not work like that. Webservers uses request-response modells. When your php finishes, the server kills the process, ei. `$city` and everything else are destroied. After it, you get the user's location. If you want something from the server again, you must send a new request, because `index.php`'s process is no longer available. This is impossible to get the city's name before you get it from the client, and you can't get the location from the client at the moment he first requests `index.php`, neither you can access an already-non-running process.

All you need to do is run your SQL query inside `geolocation.php`. When you get the result from Google, then fetch the data from your database. There `$city` doesn't contain any HTML codes, only the plain city name. Then send back some data related to that city to the user, and display it.

Comment: I want to display current location of the user on index page and show MySql results related to that city. For that I'm using ajax to post lat, lng to PHP page to get exact city name and use it on index.php without refresh the page for that I passed the vale into #htlmlocation id   . To fetch  MySQL records related to that city, I need to pass the ajax respond in to PHP variable.

Comment: I tried to store in session but it need at least one refresh of the page

Comment: Have you read what I wrote..? You'll never able to load city related data on the first page load, that's why you need to use AJAX call. Using session is useless.

Answer (score 0):

initially start session in PHP using

```
sessionstart()
```

method. then add this code after above code.
First set session using Jquery as below:

```
$.session.set("yoursessioname", "storevalue");
```

then try to get this session variable in PHP as below:

```
$city = $_SESSION['yoursessioname'];
```

I haven't tried it yet. I Hope it helps. :)

Comment: you can set session variable in success function using Jquery

Comment: The [client-side session](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin) and server-side PHP session are different things.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP in built function `strip_tags` to remove HTML tags from your statement to get only City in variable like below:

```
$city = strip_tags('<span id="htmllocation">Visakhapatnam</span>');
// Output will be Visakhapatnam only
```

Comment: correct your answer before somebody down voted it gives empty results

Comment: @AseshaGeorge check it separately at your localhost server or check it any php tester site like http://phptester.net/ it must work fine.

Comment: @AseshaGeorge make sure that city is actually coming at $data->results[0]->address_components[$j]->long_name

Comment: yes amit it should work. Please check the question, its not <span id="htmllocation">Visakhapatnam</span>its just an id in span <span id="htmllocation"></span>  which displaying  Visakhapatnam